# Using nvm in a makefile to switch node environment

Tags: node.js, makefile, nvm

I am trying to use Makefile to build Node projects. As a first step, I want to set node version using NVM. I tried the following code for that:

```
.PHONY: viz-ui
viz-ui:
    . ${HOME}/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 14.17.0
    node -v
```

I set `nvm use 16` before running make to test the output. After running `make viz-ui`, I get the following output:

```
. /home/vijayth2/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 14.17.0
Now using node v14.17.0 (npm v6.14.13)
node -v
v16.14.2
```

In short, the node switch to 14.17.0 is not reflecting in the makefile, how can i fix it? Or what is the gap in my understanding of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every line of a recipe is run in a brand-new shell. Therefore, when you reach `node -v` line, it is executed in a new shell that knows nothing about previous one that has set up different node version (this was executed in a separate shell and long gone).

You have basically two options:

1. Rewrite the recipe so that it all runs in a single shell invocation, e.g.:

```
.PHONY: viz-ui
viz-ui:
    . ${HOME}/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm use 14.17.0; \
    node -v
```

or

2. Make use of [`.ONESHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution) directive, so that all the recipe is executed in a single shell.

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand. ONESHELL is what I am looking for. Because I have a series of commands after that.

Answer (score 0):

I used `make` as the event handler for *"File Watchers"* in **PhpStorm**. It doesn't load `.bashrc`. I also checked [this](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1446) thread. No answer was a solution.

Finally this working:

```
example-target:
    NVM_DIR="$${HOME}/.nvm" && . "$${NVM_DIR}/nvm.sh" && nvm use
```